# How to transpile ES6 code to ES5 java script in eclipse with watcher

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ecmascript-6

I want to use ES6 in production environment, but IE11 and safari doesn't support these features.
So I want to setup any transpiler in eclipse which convert ES6 code to plain javascript every time when I update js files in project.

I also tried babel, but didn't find any suitable documentation to do this setup.

Comment: @SLaks, Actually I am restricted to eclipse, because my project needs some configurations which only eclipse allow me to do in such a flexible way.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining that eclipse offers a more flexible way to do web based programming compared to other editors. Which configurations are you referring to?

Comment: That is Apache Ivy configuration and many other, And I am also restricted to eclipse because it is difficult to upgrade all the developers of my organisation to some other IDE at once. For a time being I want to setup this thing in eclipse only.

Comment: You can do this via an [Ant script as project builder](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm).

Comment: ECMAScript 6 code is by definition plain JavaScript.

Comment: Could anyone please help me with a step by step guide?
I just want to setup watcher which will watch the changes in js files and automatically generate a file for ES5 code from ES6 code.

I am using gradle for building my project, but I require a way which will convert files dynamically while writing code, instead of converting the file only while building the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try invoking the necessary command line as an External Tool, and then make that a Builder on the project as @howlger directed you. Note that while this can address the *integration* issue, the underlying transpiling issue would still need to be solved. Maybe https://babeljs.io/ ?

https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-exttools.htm